# Как сбросить все checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сбросить все `checkbox` при нажатии кнопки используя jQuery или javascript?

Comment: $('input').prop('checked', false); Как то так попробуй =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам поможет [селектор :checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) и метод [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1">Один<Br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="2" checked="checked">Два<Br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" value="3">Три<Br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb5" value="4">Четыре<Br>
<button>Нажми меня</button>
```